# Rails 4: How to sign in in basecamp without api?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, basecamp

I am working on rails 4 application for creating basecamp [widget](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/id599139477) and i wants to connect with my basecamp account without using basecamp api. I did some work on it...

controller.rb

```
class Participant::HomeController < ApplicationController
  require 'basecamp_service'
  def basecamp
    @activity_image = BasecampService.fetch_data_from_web
  end
end
```

services/basecamp_service.rb

```
class BasecampService
  require 'open-uri'
  def self.fetch_data_from_web
    doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open('https://basecamp.com'))
    doc.to_html
  end
end
```

Form this code, I fetch basecamp sign in page. I need to sign in after entering username and password. Is there any gem or services for connect with basecamp or any other solution for this issue??

Thanks in advance

Comment: First of all you can not use `nokogiri` to sign in. You will need something like `selenium`. Or you can use a combination of `Mechanize and Nokogiri`

Comment: @uhn-nohn-Thnaks for the reply. I think it's long process. Is there any easy way for create basecamp widget like iPhone application?

Comment: Yes, use their api gem.